# Start Menu right-side items missing in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, start-menu, user-profiles

A Windows installation under my care has suddenly started behave rather erratically. One of the user profiles now has a Start Menu where *all* the right-side items are missing.

[image: Missing right-side items in Start Menu]

There's another user profile on the same machine where things are still OK, so it seems like the issue is with the user profile itself.

Short of deleting the user profile, what can be done about this issue?

System is Windows Vista x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click in the blank area below the flower, and select "Properties", then play with the settings to switch the files back on.